# How do I get Kudu to leave out a few folders from my repo?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have a git repo with a website that has the following structure:

```
repo_root:
 - what_a_nice_day_it_is_today.txt
 reference
  - countries.txt
 docs
  - foo.txt
 src
  - index.html
  content
    - index.css
  scripts
    - index.js
```

I have created an Azure **App Service** using the **Web App** template for my web application. In the **Deployment Center**, I have chosen to deploy from my **GitHub** repo and have chosen **Kudu** as the build server.

How do I get Kudu to not copy anything *other than the contents of the `src` folder (and its subfolders)* when deploying my web app?

That is, I want it to *leave out* the `docs` folder and the `reference` folder and any file that's in the `repo_root` but not in the `src` folder, which, in this example is the `what_a_nice_day_it_is_today.txt` file.

Comment: you can just remove them from the repo with gitignore?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I want them in the repo because I want to maintain them. I just don't want them deployed.

Comment: ok, sorry, cant think of a way to do that. sorry (doesnt mean it doesnt exist)

Answer (score 1):

Define SCM_TARGET_PATH and PROJECT env accordingly.   See https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-inplace-and-without-repository.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this points to the solution that the OP needs.  However, it'd be worth detailing the purpose of the PROJECT env specifically.